# couchDB: download results of list query as attachment

Tags: html, jquery, couchdb, couchapp

I have a list that produces a csv file. Querying that is simple, and if it is queryied from a link, it downloads the response as an attachment (provided the correct headers are sent).

However, I need to POST a potentially large amount of dynamically generated data (an array of keys). It's too large to just append to the url, i need to post the data as, well, data.

My usual ajax query is:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'text',
url: '/' + treatmentDatabaseString + '/_design/webview/_list/treatmentTable/treatmentTable?include_docs=true'
data: JSON.stringify({
    'keys': keys    // DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE POSTED
}),
error: function(status) {
    alert('db error (keyed): ' + JSON.stringify(status));
},
success: function(data) {   
//  ..do stuff
}           
});
```

Is there some way that I can alter the link so that it posts this data? or any other way I can make the result of this query download as an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming data is supposed to be JSON, you need to set `contentType` to `application/json` in your `ajax` call.